# Include file that has the same name as the URL script name

Tags: php, include, require

I'm having a strange result when I include a file that is located in a sub dire. When I try to include a file that has the same name as the first caller file (same .php file appears in the URL) it includes nothing/blank/no action. Not sure what happens exactly. 
But when I change the required file name, it works fine.

I tried to require_once a file called import.php which is located in a sub dir under `view/parts/import.php` but nothing happens, not even error. But when I changed it's name to `view/parts/v_import.php` it got required successfully.

Here's the scenario.

This is my project structure:

[image]

In `import.php` I declare `class_view.php` which is responsible for calling view files.

**In import.php**

```
include 'system/class_system.php';    
 $sys->s_view->view("import");
```

Which will start a series of events to build the page structure (header, body)
, footer etc) and will set the require template name.

**In class_view.php - View Function:**

```
private function build_view($tpl)
{
    require_once "parts/header.php";
    require_once "parts/nav.php";
    $data[] = $tpl . ".php";
    require_once "parts/body.php";
}
```

**Body Code:**

inside body.php you will find the following code:

```
    if (isset($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $value) {
            require_once $value;
        }
    } else {
        echo "No data!";
    }
```

Running XAMPP 1.8.3 [PHP: 5.5.15]

Comment: Does it work if you use `require` instead of `require_once`?

Comment: I did not think of that. Well yeah, the strange thing is that it seems it's trying to include it self (the same script called in URL) :/
I got *Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class class_system* which means it was calling the main outer file.

Comment: What is the value of `$tpl`? Are you sure it includes the directory prefix?

Comment: "import" which was passed in view("import"), view() only validates before calling build_view($tpl).

Comment: If you just give a filename, it will look in the current directory first, and only use the search path if it's not found there.

Comment: You mean it will check the root first, then will search in **view/parts**? If I give it **$sys->s_view->view("view/parts/import.php");** I get **failed to open stream: No such file** and based on my understanding, since body.php is doing the **require_once** it will look into **parts** directory only.

Comment: If you want it to look in parts, add it to the path: `$data[] = 'parts/' . $tpl . ".php";`

Comment: looking into parts alone gave me an error, but looking into 'view/parts/' .$tpl.'.php' worked fine. It seems I wasn't understanding the concept @Barmar mentioned, which it will look into the first directory first, then will look into the inner current directory.Please feel free to add this explanation as an answer and I shall accept it gladly.